# Facing ClassNotFound Exception while using jmockit to mock system time even class file is there in class folder of web-inf

Tags: java

I am using jmockit.jar to mock the system date but I am getting below error.

```
Exception in DoGet of Servletjava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No class with name "com.timeshifter.SystemTimeShifter$SystemMock" found
Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-AsyncTimeout" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No class with name "com.timeshifter.SystemTimeShifter$SystemMock" found
    at mockit.internal.util.Utilities.loadClass(Utilities.java:76)
    at mockit.internal.MockingBridge.callMock(MockingBridge.java:158)
    at mockit.internal.MockingBridge.invoke(MockingBridge.java:77)
    at java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis(System.java)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$AsyncTimeout.run(JIoEndpoint.java:152)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Exception in thread "ajp-bio-8009-AsyncTimeout" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No class with name "com.timeshifter.SystemTimeShifter$SystemMock" found
    at mockit.internal.util.Utilities.loadClass(Utilities.java:76)
    at mockit.internal.MockingBridge.callMock(MockingBridge.java:158)
    at mockit.internal.MockingBridge.invoke(MockingBridge.java:77)
    at java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis(System.java)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$AsyncTimeout.run(JIoEndpoint.java:152)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Exception in thread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No class with name "com.timeshifter.SystemTimeShifter$SystemMock" found
    at mockit.internal.util.Utilities.loadClass(Utilities.java:76)
    at mockit.internal.MockingBridge.callMock(MockingBridge.java:158)
    at mockit.internal.MockingBridge.invoke(MockingBridge.java:77)
    at java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis(System.java)
    at java.util.logging.LogRecord.<init>(LogRecord.java:185)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:827)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:185)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.error(DirectJDKLog.java:151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1533)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-1" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No class with name "com.timeshifter.SystemTimeShifter$SystemMock" found
    at mockit.internal.util.Utilities.loadClass(Utilities.java:76)
    at mockit.internal.MockingBridge.callMock(MockingBridge.java:158)
    at mockit.internal.MockingBridge.invoke(MockingBridge.java:77)
    at java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis(System.java)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread.<init>(TaskThread.java:29)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThreadFactory.newThread(TaskThreadFactory.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.<init>(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:610)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:924)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processWorkerExit(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1017)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1163)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-Acceptor-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No class with name "com.timeshifter.SystemTimeShifter$SystemMock" found
    at mockit.internal.util.Utilities.loadClass(Utilities.java:76)
    at mockit.internal.MockingBridge.callMock(MockingBridge.java:158)
    at mockit.internal.MockingBridge.invoke(MockingBridge.java:77)
    at java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis(System.java)
    at java.util.logging.LogRecord.<init>(LogRecord.java:185)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:827)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:185)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.error(DirectJDKLog.java:151)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:250)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

The above issue is happening when I am using jmockit in struts1 application. It is running fine in java project.

Steps

1. added jmockit jar file to buildpath in eclipse.
2. List item created SystemTimeShifter class under package com.timeshifter.
3. we have customized the struts1 front controller and called the method   setupSystemTime in doGet method of customized filter.

Please suggest what mistake I am doing.

## Definition of SystenTimeShifter class

```
package com.timeshifter;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;


import mockit.Mock;
import mockit.MockClass;
import mockit.Mockit;

/**
 * Class changes the system time returned by {@link System#currentTimeMillis()} via JMockit weaving.
 * <p/>
 * Original System class can be restored any time calling {@link #reset()} method. There are a few ways how to specify modified system time:
 * <ul>
 * <li>setting ms offset via {@link #setOffset(long)}
 * <li>changing ms offset (relatively) via {@link #changeOffset(long)}
 * <li>setting new date, time or ISO date/time via {@link #setIsoDate(String)}
 * </ul>
 * <p/>
 * Any of these methods can be used through system properties (-D) this way (first property in this order is used, others ignored):
 * <ul>
 * <li>{@code -Dsystime.offset=1000} - shift by one second to the future (negative number can be used)
 * <li>{@code -Dsystime.millis=1000} - set system time one second after start of the era (1970...)
 * <li>{@code -Dsystime.iso=2000-01-01T00:00:47} - 47 seconds after beginning of the 2000, alternatively you can set only time (00:00:47, date stays current) or
 * only date (2000-01-01, current time) without 'T' in both cases.
 * </ul>
 * <p/>
 * There must be something that causes class load, otherwise nothing happens. In order to allow this without modifying the original program, one may use this
 * class as a main class with original main class as the first argument (they will be correctly shifted when served to the original class). If no relevant
 * property is specified via -D, nothing happens. In any case (programmatic or main class replacement) this class has to be on a classpath. For application
 * server usage this means it has to be in its system libraries, not in EAR/WAR that is not loaded during the AS start yet.
 * <p/>
 * Example:
 * 
 * <pre>
 * java -Dsystime.iso=2000-01-01T00:00:47 SystemTimeShifter my.uber.appserver.Main arg1 second "third long with spaces"
 * </pre>
 * <b>WARNING:</b> Sun/Oracle HotSpot JVM and its inline optimization may mess up with the mock after it is set up, so if you notice that the time
 * returns to normal after number of invocations, you should add {@code -XX:-Inline} option to your java command line. Other JVM specific options
 * may be needed for different JVM implementations.
 * 
 * @author <a href="mailto:virgo47@gmail.com">Richard "Virgo" Richter</a>
 */
public class SystemTimeShifter {
    /**
     * System property setting ms offset.
     */
    public static final String PROPERTY_OFFSET = "systime.offset";

    /**
     * System property setting "current" millis.
     */
    public static final String PROPERTY_MILLIS = "systime.millis";

    /**
     * System property setting ISO date/time (or date, or time).
     */
    public static final String PROPERTY_ISO_DATE = "systime.iso";

    private static final long INIT_MILLIS = System.currentTimeMillis();
    private static final long INIT_NANOS = System.nanoTime();
    private static long offset;

    private static boolean mockInstalled;

    @Deprecated
    protected SystemTimeShifter() {
        // prevents calls from subclass
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    static {
        String isoDate = System.getProperty(PROPERTY_ISO_DATE);
        String millis = System.getProperty(PROPERTY_MILLIS);
        String offset = System.getProperty(PROPERTY_OFFSET);
        try {
            if (isoDate != null) {
                setIsoDate(isoDate);
            } else if (millis != null) {
                setMillis(Integer.parseInt(millis));
            } else if (offset != null) {
                setOffset(Integer.parseInt(offset));
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap main to allow time shifting before actually loading the real main class. Real
     * main class must be the first argument, it will be removed from the list when calling the
     * real class. Without using any relevant -D property there will be no time shifting.
     * 
     * @param args argument list with original (desired) class as the first argument
     * @throws Exception may happen during the reflection call of the other main
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String[] newArgs = new String[args.length - 1];
        System.arraycopy(args, 1, newArgs, 0, args.length - 1);

        Class clazz = Class.forName(args[0]);
        Method main = clazz.getMethod("main", newArgs.getClass());
        main.invoke(null, (Object) newArgs);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the new "system" time to specified ISO time. It is possible to set exact time with the format {@code yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss} (no apostrophes around T
     * in the actual string!) or one can set just time
     * (then current date stays) or just date (then current time stays).
     * <p/>
     * If parse fails for whatever reason, nothing is changed.
     * 
     * @param isoDate String with ISO date (date+time, date or just time)
     */
    public static synchronized void setIsoDate(String isoDate) {
        try {
            if (isoDate.indexOf('T') != -1) { // it's date and time (so "classic" ISO timestamp)
                long wantedMillis = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(isoDate).getTime();
                offset = wantedMillis - millisSinceClassInit() - INIT_MILLIS;
            } else if (isoDate.indexOf(':') != -1) { // it's just time we suppose
                Calendar calx = Calendar.getInstance();
                calx.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(isoDate));

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calx.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calx.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
                cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, calx.get(Calendar.SECOND));
                offset = cal.getTimeInMillis() - millisSinceClassInit() - INIT_MILLIS;
            } else { // it must be just date then!
                Calendar calx = Calendar.getInstance();
                calx.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(isoDate));

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calx.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, calx.get(Calendar.MONTH));
                cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, calx.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                offset = cal.getTimeInMillis() - millisSinceClassInit() - INIT_MILLIS;
            }
            mockSystemClass();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets ms offset against current millis (not against real, instead changes current value relatively).
     * 
     * @param offset relative ms offset against "current" millis
     */
    public static synchronized void changeOffset(long offset) {
        SystemTimeShifter.offset += offset;
        mockSystemClass();
    }

    /**
     * Sets ms offset against real millis (rewrites previous value).
     * 
     * @param offset new absolute ms offset against real millis
     */
    public static synchronized void setOffset(long offset) {
        SystemTimeShifter.offset = offset;
        mockSystemClass();
    }

    /**
     * Sets current millis to the specified value.
     * 
     * @param timestamp new value of "current" millis
     */
    public static synchronized void setMillis(long timestamp) {
        offset = timestamp - INIT_MILLIS;
        mockSystemClass();
    }

    /**
     * Resets the whole System time shifter and removes all JMockit stuff. Real system call is restored.
     */
    public static synchronized void reset() {
        Mockit.tearDownMocks(System.class);
        mockInstalled = false;
        offset = 0;
        System.out.println("Current time millis mock REMOVED");
    }

    private static void mockSystemClass() {
        if (!mockInstalled) {
            Mockit.setUpMock(SystemMock.class);
            System.out.println("Current time millis mock INSTALLED: " + new Date());
            mockInstalled = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Current time millis mock probably INSTALLED previously: " + new Date());
        }
    }

    public static boolean isMockInstalled() {
        return mockInstalled;
    }

    /**
     * Handy if you set up the mock by some other means like {@link Mockit#setUpStartupMocks(Object...)}.
     *
     * @param mockInstalled true if you want to pretend that the mock is already in place (or is/will be installed otherwise)
     */
    public static void setMockInstalled(boolean mockInstalled) {
        SystemTimeShifter.mockInstalled = mockInstalled;
    }

    /**
     * Returns real time millis based on nano timer difference (not really a call to {@link System#currentTimeMillis()}.
     * 
     * @return real time millis as close as possible
     */
    public static long currentRealTimeMillis() {
        return INIT_MILLIS + millisSinceClassInit();
    }

    private static long millisSinceClassInit() {
        return (System.nanoTime() - INIT_NANOS) / 1000000;
    }

    @MockClass(realClass = System.class)
    public static class SystemMock {
        /**
         * Fake current time millis returns value modified by required offset.
         *
         * @return fake "current" millis
         */
        @Mock
        public static long currentTimeMillis() {
            return INIT_MILLIS + offset + millisSinceClassInit();
        }
    }

    public static void setupSystemTime() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        SystemTimeShifter.setMockInstalled(true); // because of the setUpStartupMocks further, which sets up the mock
        SystemTimeShifter.setIsoDate("2017-01-26T10:00:00"); // this set's the offset - but doesn't set up the mock (thanks to the assert above)

        // this line performs all the suite scope magic

        /*Class c= Class.forName("com.timeshifter.SystemTimeShifter$SystemMock");

        Mockit.setUpStartupMocks(c);*/
        Mockit.setUpStartupMocks(SystemTimeShifter.SystemMock.class);
    }

    public static void resetSystemTime() {
        SystemTimeShifter.reset();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after doing some R&D I came to know that jmockit.jar library uses jdk classloader to load the victim class and because we are using web dynamic application and in dynamic web application tomcat uses its own classloader. So all the jars available in lib folder and all the classes available in web-inf/classess folder will be visible to tomcat class loader only and it would not be visible to jdk classlaoder. Hence to make victim class visible to jdk classloader copy and paste package conataining that class in jmockit.jar and then paste this jar file in ext folder of jdk so that it can be visible to jdk classloader also. make sure jmockit.jar file should also be available in application lib folder. After doing this configuration the problem got resolved.